# Getting the site collection url for 2007 to O365

Tags: javascript, spservices, jsom

I'm trying to figure out how to get the site collection url for any version of SharePoint, not sure which method would be the best

I figure using `window.location` probably isn't reliable, clientContext I don't think is available in 2007, SPServices i'm not sure I need to make a web call for just this and that seems excessive.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score -1):

It will work using `window.location`.

Try with this:

> var SiteColUrl = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host +
>   _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;

For Example:
URL: http://yourdomain/sites/hr/pages/default.aspx
`_spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl` returns: `/sites/hr`

Comment: pagecontextinfo isn't available in 2007 also siteServerRelativeUrl doesn't work if I'm inside a subsite.